# turn off frame number in certain slides using the beamer package

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I'm preparing a presentation and I would like to have transition slides without any noise, so I want to remove even the frame number (which I need for non-transition slides).

I modified the footer of the slides such that I insert the frame number instead of the page number:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[10pt]{\scriptsize{\color{blue}\insertframenumber}}\hspace{2mm}}}}
```

How can I turn off the frame number in these transitions slides.

The full MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn, usenames, table]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{default}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\hfill\makebox[10pt]{\scriptsize{\color{blue}\insertframenumber}}\hspace{2mm}}}}
}

% comment to show navigation bar
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}


% transition slide
\begin{frame}
  {\huge 
   \begin{center}
   {\color{blue} Transition} 
   \end{center}
  }
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\begin{frame}[plain]` for those transition slides.

Comment: Yes, but then the frame number gets increased too.

Comment: Add `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` after every transition frame

Comment: That solved it.

Comment: Or use '\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{My Title} \end{frame}' to get unnumered slides

Comment: That last one didn't work as it was showing the page number. But if I change it to `'\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]` then it hides the number and doesn't increase the count, so I guess it's the solution.

Comment: @aaragon: Could you write up a solution for this? Preferably write a macro like `\newcommand{\transitionslide}{%
  \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
    \huge\centering
    \textcolor{blue}{Transition}
\end{frame}
}` for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 14):

I also had a custom footers and using a combination of both `plain` and `noframenumbering` worked for me. This removes any footnotes and does not increase the frame increment.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
% Custom numbering for the footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \raisebox{5pt}{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
      \hfill\makebox[10pt]{%
        \footnotesize\insertframenumber
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        Super cool content.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```